# How to auto import dependency framework in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a module `LibGame`, which contains some helpers on top of SpriteKit.

Now I want to auto import `SpriteKit` whenever I import `LibGame`. Because most likely the module depending on my `LibGame` will use `SpriteKit` too.

This is similar to UIKit: if I import UIKit, I can use things like `CGFloat`, which means `CoreGraphics` is auto imported when I import UIKit.

How can I do this?

Note: I am using swift when I create the framework, but I do see a `LibGame.h` file as well in my module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you are looking for `@_exported`:

`@_exported import SpriteKit`

[Would you like to know more?](https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/01/19/simplifying-swift-framework-development/)

Comment: where to put this line?

Comment: Afaik somewhere in a file within your lib should be enough.